# Laravel 5.2 Extending Eloquent Builder with Reuseable Methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using logic like this in several places to retrieve a user and their profile:

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $ids)
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->with([
        'profile' => function ($query) {
            $query->addSelect(['id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
        },
    ])->get();
```

I'd like to make certain parts of this into a reuseable method for chaining:

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $ids)
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->withSimpleProfile() // use default columns
    ->get();
```

And/or

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $ids)
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->withSimpleProfile(['id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
    ->get();
```

Where `withSimpleProfile` would contain something like:

```
public function withSimpleProfile($columns) 
{
    $this->with([
        'profile' => function ($query) use ($columns) {
            $query->addSelect(['id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
        }]);

    return $this;
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE**

There does appear to be a method [macro](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_macro) in the builder, but  can't figure out where/how it might be used.

**ALTERNATIVE (unsatisfying solution)**

Typically for reuseable methods I make a UserRepository, but that would contain the original code example for invoking, but I'd like to add custom chained methods to the query to simplify reuse and not have it so tightly coupled.  Seems like the most likely way is to create my own `Illuminate/Eloquent/Builder.php` and add the method and somehow use this builder instead?  But, Laravel always has these great ways to make extending easier it seems.

This appears to work for now and continues to use DI of UserRepository, but for some reason it doesn't feel quite refined:

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $ids)
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->with($this->users->simpleProfile())
    ->get();
```

Where the UserRepository::simpleProfile returns:

```
public function simpleProfile() {

    return [
        'profile' => function ($query) {
            $query->addSelect(['id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
        },
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does scope solve your problem?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: It sure looks like it.  Especially with the fact dynamic scoping is also included.  Cheers!

Comment: No! It is not recommended to use a scopes for extending builder because eloquent isolate scopes and you won't get the same query with scope as you would without scope.